# How can I manually pin a URL to the Windows 8 start screen?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, start-screen

The only way I've found so far to pin a URL to the start screen, is to load this URL in Internet Explorer, then click `Pin`, and `Pin to Start`.

The problem is, it forces me to *load* the URL, which then redirects to another URL with a temporary token.

I don't want to pin this temporary URL, I want to manually pin the original URL.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Rather easy:

- Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run `shell:programs`.
- This should open the classic "Programs" folder with Start Menu groups.
- Right click and create a new shortcut (you can create your own sub folder/group for this), use your target URL and name it as you want.
- Close the folder.
- Hit <kbd>Win+S</kbd>, type the name you've chosen in the steps before.
- Select the correct icon/search result, right click and pin it to start.

Just keep in mind that this won't create a pinned site and might use a different icon.
However, you can just drag&drop a site out of IE instead of creating a shortcut and should be good to go.